# InvokedAtIndex matcher in PHPUnit is not verifying if reaches last prepared index

Tags: php, phpunit

when i write a test, that is testing several mock calls in certain order, I also want to be sure, that all prepared function call were called. I am using `InvokedAtIndex` matcher but for example this code in test case passes:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Service', 'SomeClass');
$mock->expects($this->at(0))->method('getSomeValue');
$mock->expects($this->at(1))->method('getSomeOtherValue');

$mock->getSomeValue();
```

Is there some solution how to achieve this test to fail because not all prepared mock methods was called?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your example `MethodName` matcher doesn't throw an exception, but instead of that just returns false. This means that the sequencer will work properly only with appropriate method (for example if you'll create stubs from example mocks) but it won't make expectation failed.

If you want check if at the first time `getSomeValue` method is called and on the second one `getSomeOtherValue` you need to involved another `InvocationMocker` - for example `with`.

So, that should work for you (assuming there are no argument in both methods):

```
(...)
$mock->expects($this->at(0))->method('getSomeValue')->with();
$mock->expects($this->at(1))->method('getSomeOtherValue')->with();

$mock->getSomeValue();
```

Above test will fail unless your call `getSomeOtherValue` at the second invocation.

Comment: AFAICT, `->with()` is a no-op. It doesn't actually test that no arguments were passed to the method.

Comment: Yes - you are right. And that is exactly what I want. The only thing I want to do was involve InvactionMocker to make expectations work. (pay attention that the test has to check if method getSomeValue was called before getSomeOtherValue)

Comment: I think I just learned something about PHPUnit... That `->with()` actually is needed somewhere. Thanks!